# Disable checkbox having different date

Tags: javascript, php

```
  <?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="checkbox" 
                 id="<?php echo $row['invoice_id']; ?>" 
                 name="invoice_id[]" 
                 rel="<?php echo $row['due_date']; ?>" 
                 value="<?php echo $row['invoice_id'];?>">
       </td>
       <td><?php echo $row['invoice_no']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['due_date']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

my question is how to disable all check box which is not equal to due date of the first check box checked

example

```
invoice_no              due_date
1                       10-15-2014
2                       10-15-2014
3                       10-16-2014
4                       10-17-2014
```

if i checked invoice_no 1, invoice_no 3 and 4 will be disabled
and if i unchecked invoice_no 1, all check_box will be enabled

as of now i only have this and don't know whats next thing to do, i search the web but still i cant find how to do this

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    $due_date = $(this).attr("rel"); 
});
```

TIA for your help.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
 //alert($(this).attr("rel"));
 $due_date = $(this).attr("rel");
 $id = $(this).val();
    
    var $check = false;
    
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
   if($(this).val()!=$id){
    if($(this).attr("rel")==$due_date){
     $(this).prop('disabled',false);
    }else{
     $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    }
   }
  });
 }else{
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
            if($(this).val()!=$id & $(this).is(':checked')){
                $check = true;
            }
  });
        if(!$check){    
            $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
               $(this).prop('disabled',false);
            });
        }
 }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" 
                 id="1" 
                 name="invoice_id[]" 
                 rel="10-15-2014" 
                 value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" 
                 id="2" 
                 name="invoice_id[]" 
                 rel="10-15-2014" 
                 value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" 
                 id="3" 
                 name="invoice_id[]" 
                 rel="10-16-2014" 
                 value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" 
                 id="4" 
                 name="invoice_id[]" 
                 rel="10-17-2014" 
                 value="4">
```

This will work.. :)

Comment: when i checked 2 invoice then unchecked 1 out of 2, then every checkbox will be enabled.

Comment: @Sammy  can you please give me a reason what is need for if($(this).val()!=$id) this condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
        var chk = $(this).attr('rel');
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){

                        var chks = $(this).attr('rel');
                        if(chk != chks)
                        {
                           $(this).attr('disabled','true'); 
                        }
                });
         }
        else
        {
            var temp ='';
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){                    
                    if($(this).is(':checked'))
                    {
                        temp = $(this).attr('rel');                               
                        return false;                                
                    }                       
            });

            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){                    

                    if(temp != chk)
                    {
                        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');                            
                    }                       
            });
        }
});

</script>
```

Comment: its working great thank you, although there is a little error ex. when i checked 2 invoice then unchecked 1 out of 2, then every checkbox will be enabled.

Comment: Updated else part please check again